# Angularjs: Injecting one controller in another failed

Tags: angularjs

I have this controller A which I'm trying to inject in every other controller.
What controller A does is, it communicates with a factory (which does some authentication services, communicates with database)

My factory looks like this and I named it `myFactoryServices.js` and included the link to it in my index page.

```
(function() {

angular
.module('myApp.myFactoryServices', [])

.factory('FactoryService', ["$http", "$location", function($http, $location){
    var my = this;
    my.someFunction = function()
    {
        //communiate with backend and return data
    }
    return my;
}]);

})();
```

and my Controller A looks like this:

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('myApp.ControlA', [])

        .controller('ControllerA', function($scope,$routeParams, FactoryService) {
            var my = this;      
            FactoryService.someFunction();

        });
})();
```

And I am trying to inject this controller in every other controller, but it does not work. I am pretty new to this kind of programming, can anyone tell me where I made mistake?

This is how I tried injecting a controller into another.

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('myApp.ControlB', [])

        .factory('ControllerBService', function($http) {
            var baseUrl = 'backendurl/';
            return {
                getInfo: function() {
                    return $http.get(baseUrl+ 'getInfo');
                }
            };
        })

        .controller('ControllerB', function($scope,$routeParams, ControllerBService,ControllerA) {
                var my = this;      

        });
})();
```

No error is coming, and the controller is not getting injected as I am not able to use those factory services. is this the correct method?

Comment: Cotnrollers are not injectable. If you want to share some behavior use service/factory for that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you cannot inject controller to another controller, and One simple solution would be, instead of having each angular modules for each components, declare a module and add the factory service to controllers as dependency.

**Code:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.factory('FactoryService', ["$http", "$location", function($http, $location){
    var my = this;
    my.someFunction = function()
    {
        //communiate with backend and return data
    }
    return my;
}]);

app.controller('ControllerA', function($scope,$routeParams, FactoryService) 
 {
   var my = this;      
   FactoryService.someFunction();

});

app.controller('ControllerB', function($scope,$routeParams, FactoryService)
{
    var my = this;      
    FactoryService.someFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are not injectable, because controller is not singleton. Controllers are constructor functions used to create instances of controllers. For example you can have multiple instances of one controller in your app:

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('Example', function () {
    this.x = Math.random();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  First instance: <br>
  <div ng-controller="Example as Ex1">
    {{Ex1.x}}
  </div>
  Second  instance: <br>
  <div ng-controller="Example as Ex2">
    {{Ex2.x}}
  </div>
</div>
```

So if you want to share some behavior between controller you should use factory instead.

Answer (score 0):

To inject a controller into another controller, use the `$controller` service.

```
app.controller('ControllerB', function($scope,$routeParams, $controller) {
        var my = this;  
        $scope.ctrlA = $controller("ControllerA", {$scope: $scope});    

});
```

The above example creates an instance of `ControllerA as ctrlA` with its `$scope` injected with the scope of the parent controller.

For more information, see [AngularJS $controller Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller).